# Scala - Futures not starting

Tags: scala, concurrency

I want to start two workers on a Future method called `extraire_phrases` . I call them in my main, but it seems that the Promise is never fulfilled and I don't get anything at the end of my main, as if the workers don't start. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

```
object Main {

    val chemin_corpus:String = "src/corpus.txt"
    val chemin_corpus_backup:String = "src/tartarinalpes.txt"
    val chemin_dictionnaire:String = "src/dicorimes.dmp"
    val chemin_dictionnaire_backup:String = "src/dicorimes2.dmp"

    def main(args:Array[String]){

        val quatrain = Promise[List[Phrase]]()

        var grosPoeme = List[Phrase]()

        Future {
          val texte_1 = Phrases.extraire_phrases(chemin_corpus, chemin_dictionnaire)
          val texte_2 = Phrases.extraire_phrases(chemin_corpus_backup, chemin_dictionnaire_backup)

          texte_1.onComplete {
            case Success(list) => {
              val poeme = new DeuxVers(list)
              poeme.ecrire :: grosPoeme
            }
            case Failure(ex) => {
              quatrain.failure(LameExcuse("Error: " + ex.getMessage))
            }
          }

          texte_2.onComplete {
            case Success(lst) => {
              val poeme2 = new DeuxVers(lst)
              poeme2.ecrire :: grosPoeme
            }
            case Failure(ex) => {
              quatrain.failure(LameExcuse("Error: " + ex.getMessage))
            }
          }
        quatrain.success(grosPoeme)
        }

        println(quatrain.future)
        println(grosPoeme)
    }

}
```

Here is what I have in my console after execution:

```
Future(<not completed>)
List()
```

Even if I remove the `Future {` before `val texte_1` it seems that none of them fire properly, texte_1 starts somehow, sometimes it works, sometimes not, and texte_2 never starts (never goes to completion). No failure either.

// Edit: Alvaro Carrasco's answer is the correct one. Thank both of you however for the help

Comment: Please mark my answer as your selected answer using the check mark next to the answer (if indeed you consider it to be). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Futures are executed asynchronously and your code won't "wait" for them to finish. `onComplete` will schedule some code to run when the future completes, but it won't force your program to wait for the result.

You need to thread the inner futures using `map/flatMap/sequence` so you end up with a single future at the end and then wait for it using `Await.result(...)`.

You don't really need `Promise` here, as exceptions will caught by the future.

Something like this:

```
object Main {

  val chemin_corpus:String = "src/corpus.txt"
  ...

  def main(args:Array[String]){
    ...

    val f1 = texte_1
      .map {list => 
        val poeme = new DeuxVers(list)
        poeme.ecrire :: grosPoeme
      }

    val f2 = texte_2
      .map {lst => 
        val poeme2 = new DeuxVers(lst)
        poeme2.ecrire :: grosPoeme
      }

    // combine both futures
    val all = for {
      res1 <- f1
      res2 <- f2
    } yield {
      println(...)
    }
    // wait for the combined future
    Await.result(all, 1.hour)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It seems that while your solution works, it fires up only f2, and if I do `println(grosPoeme)` at the `val all` it prints nothing... Ah I'm sure it's easy but I just don't get it

Comment: @VanhaerenThomas Keep in mind: a scala `List` is immutable. You can't change it. The `::` constructor gives you a brand new list. If you want to use mutation, you have to use a `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer` and call it's `append` method.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed immutable. But since I get a Future(....) at the last val all, how do I access what's inside? Creating an `all.onComplete ...` with `case Success(lst)` does not seem to work, returns nothing even with `case Success(lst) => println(lst)`

Comment: Nevermind, I have found my answer :) just put the await.result in a val:

`val x = Await.result(all, 1.hour)`

and then just call what you want on the list.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with [for-comprehension on Future](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FiLaeMaxSL69XlHsLyi0Bw). You need to change `f1` and `f2` to do what you need. `f1` and `f2` will be executed in parallel. [for-comprehension](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#functional-composition-and-for-comprehensions) gives elegant way to get the result of future(it's just syntactic sugar for compositions of operations with `flatMap`, `filter` and etc:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val f1: Future[Seq[Int]] = Future {
  // Do something here
  Seq(1, 2, 3)
}.recover { case ex =>
    // If Future fails, let's log an exception and return default value
    println(s"Unable to complete f1: $ex")
    Seq.empty[Int]
}

val f2: Future[Seq[Int]] = Future {
  // Do something here
  Seq(4, 5, 6)
}.recover { case ex =>
  // If Future fails, let's log an exception and return default value
  println(s"Unable to complete f2: $ex")
  Seq.empty[Int]
}
// f1 and f2 have started

// we use for-comprehension on Future to get the result
val f = for {
  seq1 <- f1
  seq2 <- f2
} yield seq1 ++ seq2

// Blocking current thread and wait 1 seconds for the result
val r = Await.result(f, 1.seconds)
println(s"Result: $r")
```